# How can I use a FULLTEXT query with MySQL to return all results matching a string?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the table `videos`:
[image]

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(history.v_id) AS videoCheck, MATCH (v_title, v_desc, v_tags) AGAINST ("%not%") AS relevance FROM videos LEFT JOIN history ON history.v_id = videos.v_id WHERE MATCH (v_title, v_desc, v_tags) AGAINST ("%not%") GROUP BY relevance DESC
```

I want that query to return all results with the string `not` in it but it is only returning 1 result instead of 2.

What is the best way to get it to return all matching queries instead of only 1?

---

Edit1:

If I use the `WITH QUERY EXPANSION` modifier it does return 2 results but that is still not what I want because if the string changes to for example `asd` it also only returns 2 results instead the many more which are stored.

Edit2:

Query with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(history.v_id) AS videoCheck FROM videos LEFT JOIN history ON history.v_id = videos.v_id WHERE CONCAT_WS(v_tags, v_title, v_desc) LIKE :input GROUP BY history.v_id ORDER BY videoCheck DESC
```

Comment: Fulltext search is not intended for substring searching. Use trivial LIKE (in tags - FIND_IN_SET).

Comment: I tried using `LIKE`, I edited the OP with that query but that didn't give the desired results either as it had to match a word specifically, for example if you searched for `This is a not` no results would be returned even though it should return `v_id 1` and `v_id 8`.

Comment: Your use of the word "match" does not align with MySQL's `MATCH()` or `LIKE` functions. You will probably have to write something on the client side to parse the query into individual words, then use a combination of `LIKE`, `MATCH()`, and perhaps other functions (`POSITION()`, `INSTR()`, etc.) to request the results you're looking for.

Comment: % is used with like, not with match ... against ... Your dataset is too small, your search strings may also be too short. Innodb fulltext engine does not index words shorter than 4 characters by default.

Comment: It doesn't work with strings longer than 4 characters either, it gives the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query seems to be doing what I want:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (v_title, v_desc, v_tags) AGAINST (:input) AS relevance  FROM videos WHERE MATCH (v_title, v_desc, v_tags) AGAINST (:inputWhere) ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

I don't need the `LEFT JOIN` any more as I am no longer ordering by `videoCheck`.